# Is it recommended to implement a Network Scanning service as an action method, and call this action method from external applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an ERP asp.net mvc 5 web application deployed under iis7. And now I want to implement a new scanning service, which mainly uses powercli and power shell scripts, and scan our network for servers & vms and get their specifications and their statues.

So I am thinking of the following approach:-

1.Since the scanning should be access by only specific users and requires the hosting server to have powercli and other tools installed, so I want to create a new asp.net mvc 5 web application , and deploy it under iis7 instread of modifying my current ERP syste,. Where the new application will have the following action method which will do the scan as follow:-

```
public ActionResult ScanServer(string token)
        {
// do the scan
//send n email with scanning result
}
```

2.Now inside my current ERP system I can manually initiating the scan by calling the above action method as follow:-

```
  [HttpPost]
       [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "", Model = "Admin")]
       public ActionResult Scan()
       {
           try
           {

               string currentURL = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scanningURL"];
               using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
               {
                   string url = currentURL + "home/scanserver?token=*******" ;
                   var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
                   TempData["messagePartial"] = string.Format("Scan has been completed. Scan reported generated");

               }




           }
           catch (WebException ex)
           {
               TempData["messageDangerPartial"] = string.Format("scanningservice can not be accessed");



           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               TempData["messageDangerPartial"] = string.Format("scan can not be completed");



           }
```

Now I did a quick test where I manually started the scan from the ERP and the scanning service deployed under iis worked well.

But I have these questions:-

1. The scanning service might take 20-30 minutes to complete. So from an architecture point of view is my current approach considered valid ? I mean to initiate a scan by calling an action method from another application ?
2. Now can i inside the scanning service web application, to force it to call its action method on a timly basis (for example every 4 hours)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to write a windows service to install on the webserver alongside the web app. This windows service can use threads or a timer to execute a long running task (such as scanning your network) at a specified interval and send an email when finished.

You can talk to your service from the app using the database, a config file, or maybe even a registry entry.

If this will not work for you, you can look into some task scheduling apps such as Quartz.NET. If you do use a windows service, I recommend the excellent [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) which makes it easy to create and deploy. Here is a [nice blog post I found by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) that may help.

Comment: so why i should avoid having the scanning service as an asp.net mvc web application hosted on iis ? this is how web services works.. is this correct?

Comment: also i worked with SharePoint 2013, where you can for example start a full crawl search from your browser, or re-index your search by clicking on a button inside your browser ,, and the screen keeps loading for around 30 minutes till the full search and the re-index finishes .. so does this mean that this approach used by SharePoint is not 100& robust ?

Comment: also inside my asp.net mvc web application i am using entity framework to interact with the Database,, so can i use this if i go with windows service ?

Comment: If you dont use an external process, then the request will hang around and take up one thread from the thread pool... unless you make an async action method to handle it or use an external process of some sort. I'm not sure how sharepoint handles the event as it predates the .NET 4.0 async, but I am sure it has been updated to support this.

Comment: so can you adivce more what will be the main issues when i call the scanning action method from my ERP system. this is how web services works you call a web server (the ScanServer() action method in my case) it will do the scan , update the database and when completed it will send a json ,, where the json object will be displayed inside my ERP system which initiated the scan.. so let say the sanserver action method utilize a thread on iis  during the scan,, is this a big issue ?

Comment: If your system isnt high traffic then you probably wont notice a difference. It can make a huge difference on highly scaled apps though. Just make sure that if you do use MVC then to make it async! You will have to poll the status of the scan somehow and youll need some sort of way to report the status back to the client. There are so many ways you could implement it, really.

Comment: what i am doing is that the scan action method will scan the network for server & vms, then update the database with the scan result + it will build an emailclient with the scan result and send it to  group of users. Once the scan is done and the email is send it will return a json object with the status and the duration of the scan to the ERP system which initiated the scan. now inside my asp.net mvc5 i did not use any async action method before. so i will try to keep all the action methods sync, if i notice that the performance is bad i might chnage it to be async, can you adivce?